# How do I create a new MPMediaItem with custom artwork?

Tags: iphone, ios, mpmediaitem

I have an app (iOS5+) in which I'd like to set the lock screen image with album art. Here's the thing though: my app doesn't actually play the song. So I think I need to create a new MPMediaItem with custom artwork and possibly an audio track of silence? I have a hunch I'm on the wrong track though. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: It should work but imagine the user reaction who was listening songs and then launched your app. I'm pretty sure it will be rejected for using `nowPlayingInfo` not in intended way.

Comment: I can't help but think that this won't work. If you create a MPMediaItem you can't use its metadata on the lock screen without playing it, and even if it has a silent audio track this will still cause what ever app was originally playing music to stop.

Comment: yeah, that's what I was thinking. Guess I'll try another tack on getting a programmatic lock screen image.

Comment: 0x7fffffff is correct.  There are numerous problems with what you are trying to do.  First of all, you WILL be rejected if you try to play a silent track to keep your app going in the background.  Secondly, your app has to be set up for background audio and you have to be playing it to set the artwork along with artist information to be shown in the lock screen.

Comment: I've found an app called [Slideshow](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/lock-slideshow/id485358934?mt=8) that accomplishes a changing lock screen album art by playing a silence track. That's where my research is headed at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try subclassing (no idea if artwork will work)

```
class Fakemediaitem: MPMediaItem {
    override var persistentID: MPMediaEntityPersistentID {
        get {
            return self.localPersistentId
        }
    }
    
    override var albumTrackNumber: Int {
        get {
            return Int(self.localPersistentId)
        }
    }
    
    override var title: String {
        get {
            return "Fake title"
        }
    }
    
    private var localPersistentId: MPMediaEntityPersistentID
    
    init(_ id: MPMediaEntityPersistentID) {
        self.localPersistentId = id
        super.init()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```